# Why my BIOS is being strangely behaving as both Legacy and UEFI?

Tags: windows, bios

I have `Asus Vivobook X412DA` with Windows 11. While opening BIOS, I realized the UI looked old but I have already updated it to the latest version by the MyAsus app.

[image: System info (msinfo)]

When I searched on this I found out that there are 2 types of BIOS:

- **Legacy:** Old UI and slower, supports MBR & more limitations
- **UEFI:** New UI and faster, supports GPT

Now my BIOS UI looked old, so it must have been Legacy, but in `msinfo`, it shows UEFI.
[image: BIOS UI]

Partition type also shows GPT.
[image: Disk Partition Type]

I am confused about whether the current BIOS is UEFI or Legacy & how to update it.

This is how it should have looked like:
[image: UEFI UI]

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it too much. I have a new Asus WS W680-ACE motherboard and it is exactly the same. There is no GUI but the BIOS is UEFI with blue/grey colors (looking like legacy BIOS). As long as you update to the last BIOS version from the Asus support page you are good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a long generation of UEFI BIOSes that look exactly like what you have shown first (and so also, you are right, look quite similar to legacy BIOSes).

It is only on the most recent non-gaming machines that almost all UEFI BIOSes have a graphical UI instead of coloured console text. However on machines targeted at gaming and overclocking, a GUI something like the one you've shown second has been normal for a few years.

If the BIOS says it's UEFI, I would believe it. It's possible that it's an older UEFI BIOS, and that there is a newer release, with a GUI, for that same machine. You just need to go on the manufacturer's website and scan for drivers and updates.